# Find kernel and image of linear transformation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, transformation

I am given transformation : 
$f:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$
$ f(x,y,z)=(-x+y+z,x-y+z)$

I am requested to find kernel and image of this transformation.
I am finding kernel:
$ (-x+y+z,x-y+z)=(0,0 )$

$\begin{cases}
-x+y+z=0 \\
x-y+z=0  \\
\end{cases}  \Rightarrow \begin{cases} x=y\\ z=0 \\\end{cases}$

$ Ker f = \{ (x,x,0): x\in R^{3} \} = Lin\{(1,1,0) \} $
Am I doing this right?
I have a problem with finding Im of this transformation. I do not really understand how to do this. I will be glad to be instructed how to do so.

Comment: Kernel is right. To find the image write down the matrix representation, take the transpose, then row reduce. A basis for the image is the rows that contain pivots. In this case the image is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Is it a way to this without matrix representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: the kernel is correct. Now by the Rank-Nullity theorem: $$\operatorname{rank}(f)=\dim \mathbb R^3-\dim\ker f=2=\dim \mathbb R^2$$
hence $f$ is surjective.

Comment: So that means that $dim Im f = 2$ Could you explain me how to find $Im f$ ?

Comment: $f$ is surjective means that $\operatorname{Im}(f)=\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Maybe I used bad term for this. How to find basis of $ Imf $ ?

Comment: Any basis of $\mathbb R^2$ is a basis of the image.

Comment: Thank you ! I finally understood this.

Comment: You're welcome.